# Change class automaticlly in rtl and ltr

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to adding `rtl-ltr` support for my application .
here is the question : assume that there is input like this :

```
<span class="sp-right">
    <label>
        Number:
    </label>
</span>
```

is it possible to change all `sp-right` class to `sp-left` programmatically ?

is it a good idea in ltr and rtl support in angular ?

Thanks

Comment: *"is it possible to change all sp-right class to sp-left programmatically"* Sure, it is possible. *"is it a good idea in ltr and rtl support in angular"* Depends on your app and audience. If it's needed then why not.

Comment: thx , so would you please tell me how i can achive this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery

```
$(".sp-right").each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("sp-right").addClass("sp-left");
});
```

Above code will run once only in code sequence. Put it in event listening function like:

```
$("button.trigger").click(function(){
    $(".sp-right").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("sp-right").addClass("sp-left");
    });
});
```

Then it will run when event trigger.

Or you can build a directive. I am writing for you

```
_module.directive("spRight", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.removeClass("sp-right").addClass("sp-left");
        }
    };
});
```

UPDATE:

```
app.directive("buttonThatTrigger", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',//target all elements with class button-that-trigger
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.click(function(){
                $(".sp-right").each(function(){
                    $(this).removeClass("sp-right").addClass("sp-left");
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Then add a class in button:

```
<button class="button-that-trigger"></button>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68163/discussion-between-user3642164-and-aokaddaoc).

Comment: dude, i found a solution. @dfsq helped me a lot
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763737/multiple-condition-in-each-jquery/27763757#27763805

Comment: Hi,i got an answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769294/changing-direction-in-angular/27770279#27770279

what do you think about it ?

Comment: Both answers require you to add or change form elements' attribute. If you want to get it done at once the solution will not work.

Comment: You need to store the setting. When steps change, then it will run the class fixing function. Setting can be stored in service. For steps change then run the fixing function, you need to find a eventlistener, then put the class fixing function as callback

Comment: how about store data like in .value

Comment: hey what's up buddy ? would you please check this out ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879764/hide-elemnt-if-clicked-outside-angular
thx

Answer (score 0):

One more approach. Instead of changing multiple classes on the page (although it's not that difficult), it's much more reasonable to change only one class on the top level of the application container and from there manage all the classes with CSS.

For example:

```
<span class="sp-direction">
    <label>Number:</label>
</span>
```

In CSS

```
.sp-direction {
    direction: ltr; /* default text direction */
}
.sp-right .sp-direction {
    direction: rtl;
}
.sp-left .sp-direction {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

Now all you need to do is to change `sp-right`/`sp-left` classes on say `body` tag:

```
<body class="sp-{{spClass}}">
```

And in any controller:

```
$rootScope.spClass = 'left';
$rootScope.spClass = 'right';
```

Comment: there are lots of form and class. so i'm looking for something tricky that @aokaddaoc said