# Multiple condition in .each jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my **HTML**

```
<span class="sp-right">
    <label>Name:</label>
</span>
<span class="sp-left">
    <select name="omoor" required>
        <option value="" style="display:none">something</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

I want to change `sp-right`class to `sp-left` class and `sp-left` to `sp-right` with toggle .

here is my **jquery**  :

```
$(".sp-right").each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("sp-right").addClass("sp-left");
});
```

it's working only once and for 1 element ?
Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As simple as one line with [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
$('.sp-right, .sp-left').toggleClass("sp-right sp-left");
```

No need to check for classes and remove/addClass manually, as `toggleClass` does exactly this. You can also provide multiple space separated classes to toggle.

Answer (score 1):

Check the current classname inside the function.

```
$(".sp-left, .sp-right").each(function(){
    var el = $(this);

    if (el.hasClass('sp-left')) {
        el.removeClass("sp-left").addClass("sp-right");
    } else {
        el.removeClass("sp-right").addClass("sp-left");
    }    
});
```

Comment: you can a pass function to toggleClass, no need for each!