# Changing direction in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to change sp-right class to sp-left programticlly in angular :
**Html**

```
<span class="sp-right">
    <label>
        Number:
    </label>
</span>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive("buttonThatTrigger", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',//target all elements with class button-that-trigger
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.click(function(){
               $('.sp-right, .sp-left').toggleClass("sp-right sp-left");
            });
        }
    };
});
```

It works fine , but when i click on link(ui-router) and come back it changed to original !
Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your requirements are but is there a reason why you don't use ngClass?

```
<div ng-class='whatClassIsIt(position)' ng-click='position = !position'>
```

Then you do

```
$scope.position = true;

// true=sp-right, false=sp-left
$scope.whatClassIsIt(pos){
  return pos? "sp-right" : "sp-left";
};
```

Comment: there are lots of form with this class="sp-right" . so i don't want to change all classes . Any idea ? –

Comment: You don't have to change every class, you can simply apply the ng-class above to the ones you want to change. If there are many, you make use a directive (it will save you time when you later have to add more DOM elements with the same behaviour).

Comment: The controller gets reset each time and you want to keep the state. Is that correct? You have to use a service which is global throughout your App. You inject the service into your controller. Then, at the top of your directive, you can simply say `element.attr('class', scope.state);`

Comment: the problem is this directive work once, how can i run it in each step ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember the state (in your case the direction) either in a controller which is on a level (e.g. body) that will not be replaced by ui-router or (IMO preferable) you remember the state in a service (`.service|.factory|.value`).

Example:

```
app.value('layoutState', {
        direction: 'right'
    });
```

And when you have the state in a safe place, then you could change your implementation in a more "angularish" way:

```
<span class="{{layoutState.direction === 'right' ? 'sp-right' : 'sp-left'}}">
    <label>
        Number:
    </label>
</span>
```

Your directive:

```
app.directive("buttonThatTrigger", ['layoutState', function (layoutState) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',//target all elements with class button-that-trigger
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.layoutState = layoutState;
            element.click(function(){
                layoutState.direction = layoutState.direction === 'right' ?
                    'left' : 'right';
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: there are lots of form with this class="sp-right" .
so i don't want to change all classes . Any idea ?

Comment: Can you give us a bigger picture of your html-code? Is "direction" a property of single input controls or of your forms? Please edit your question so we can read it. A comment will not be sufficient for that.