# Hide elemnt if clicked outside Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i'm new to write custom directive . I'm trying to create something like backdrop(modal ui.bootstrap) in angular.
this is the fiddle i'm working on : [**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/zqdmny41/23/)  .

here's what i want : when user click on button (top left) menu get open and **i want** to close it after click outside the menu .

**Directive** :

```
    app.directive("Trigger", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, event) {
            element.click(function(){
if (e.target.id != "parentUl" && !$(e.target).closest("#rightMenu").length) {
            $("#rightMenu").removeClass("noneStyle");
        }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

i don't know exactly if `restrict: 'C'`is suitable for this case .
Thanks for helping me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run and read comments in CSS
http://jsfiddle.net/evqw2zhp/3/

JS:

```
app.directive("trigger", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        scope: '=noneStyle',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).click(function (e) {
                $("#rightMenu").removeClass("noneStyle");
                scope.noneStyle = false;
                scope.$apply();
                console.log(scope);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

CSS:

When bottom = 0, it will cover up whole screen due to left, right, top, bottom are all 0 and position = abs.

```
#CoverUpWholeScreen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: auto;
    z-index: 1; /*higher than normal element but low than right menu */
}
```

When right menu expands, this will be cover up whole screen

```
#CoverUpWholeScreen.show {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

app.directive("trigger", function () {
Directive name should be camelcase-> thisIsAValidDirectiveName but not Pasalcase: ThisIsWrong
When you tagging it to HTML element, the name should be all lowercase and seperated by dash: this-is-a-valid-directive-name

A: tag it by attribute-> this-is-a-valid-directive-name="aValueForScope"
C: A: tag it by class-> class="this-is-a-valid-directive-name"
E: A: tag it by custom HTML element-> 
You can set restrict: 'ACE' or 'CE' whatever mix of tagging way you want at once.

scope is quite complicated, single way binding, two way binding, isolated scope, transclude scope, no scope etc. I am not very familar with how things go, so... I cannot help you much.

Let talk about scope: '=noneStyle'.
= is a symbol telling Angular bind noneStyle as two data binding. i.e.: when you update value inside this directive, source value, in parent scope(scope in controller) will also get updated, vice versa. Setting it as two way data binding is important, otherwise value is not synced.

CoverUpWholeScreen has trigger class->a directive,
when this directive element->click: remove right menu class and update controller's value.
As this is a operation outside scope(not something scope.xxx = "aaa"; or running a function in scope: scope.runFn();),
We need to call scope.$apply(); to tell angular: "Hey I changed something, update it for me.".

Reason why you should make a dummy div cover up whole screen is becasue you don't want to check mouse click event everytime for whether right menu is expanded then remove class.

And when you add elements in body, these element will block the background(the div), so shift the z-index up a bit but not the highest as it will also cover up right menu.

Comment: many thx buddy , you teach me everyday . would you please see this : http://jsfiddle.net/7f32byhn/16/
is it possible to define it globally ?

Comment: the problem is what if i have multi menu like this , for example there is accardion menu in menu , if there is something globally i can add it everywhere

Comment: I am sorry I don't what you mean. Draw sth or illustrate it more?

Comment: do you already work with modal ui in angular ? there is a backdrop option, if you set it to true , you can close the modal by clicking outside the div .

Comment: I think you can still use the solution above but change a bit. use class to target all menu then each of them remove class? When something trigger some menu to show up or expand, then that dummy will expand too, when that dummy is clicked, remove classes

Comment: I know nothing about Angular UI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68582/discussion-between-soheil-and-aokaddaoc).

Answer (score 0):

Get menu id of button on click you want to show

```
 @ViewChild('mobmenu') menu:any;
```

Write below in oninit component

```
this.renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'click', (event:any) => {
console.log(this.renderer);
if(!this.menu.nativeElement.contains(event.target)){
    this.resclass="";
} else{
    if(this.resclass=="mobile_menu")
    {
        this.resclass="";   
    }
    else{
        this.resclass="mobile_menu";        
    }

}

});
```